# Update ticket Field in zoho desk

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I'm a beginner at using Custom Function on the Zoho desk. I'm trying to update a field in the ticket template.

I have 2 fields in the ticket template [KM, COST]. The cost should equal `2*KM`. For example, if `KM = 100`, then `Cost = 200`.

I created a workflow that works if the KM is updated and attached the following custom function code, but the field doesn't update.

```
orgId = "718524341";
response = zoho.desk.getRecordById(orgId,"tickets",TicketID,"zohodesk");
cid = response.get('cf_km');
km_cost = cid * 2;
zoho.desk.update(orgId,"tickets",TicketID,{"cf":{"cf_cost":km_cost}},"zohodesk");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct API Name for the tickets module in zoho desk is `Tickets`.

If you still can't get it to work, then try executing the function independent of the workflow with fixed parameters. Make sure to do `info response` and post the output here.

Comment: I check the ticket history I found the workflow doesn't run, I don't know the problem from workflow or from the code.

Comment: I've contact with Zoho support they provide me the following code. but still not wok
`orgId = "718524343";
response = zoho.desk.getRecordById(orgId,"tickets",TicketID,"zohodesk");
cid = response.get("cf").get("cf_km");
km_cost = cid * 2;
info zoho.desk.update(orgId,"tickets",TicketID,{"cf":{"cf_cost":km_cost}},"zohodesk");`

Comment: Please execute the function by itself and add `info response;` to see what the issue is. Also please remove your org IDs from your questions by editing them